# В MODX revo. не редактируется файл, не устанавливаются модули

Tags: modx

Добрый день!

Вчера столкнулся со следующей проблемой: устанавливаю систему, все идет как обычно, но после установки и авторизации обнаруживаю, что не работает редактирование файлов и установка модулей.

Скриншоты:
https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2017/05/70a1135b8bb8fbb9a0d9f544a1ed3056.jpg
https://s8.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2017/05/b05dc1a6ef38aaa18a7b920bbae380c5.jpg

Значит сначала установил последнюю версию (2.5.7-pl) с официального сайта - не работает, результат на скринах.
Сношу, и беру со своей флехи версию постарее (2.5.0-pl) которая точно работала как есть из коробки пол года и год назад. Результат аналогичен.
Попробовал 2.4.2-pl, тоже самое...

при установке, кодировку выбираю: utf-8 general ci, сжатие CSS и JS отключаю

Спасибо!

Comment: А если скриншоты удалят с сервера, кто-нибудь поймёт ваш вопрос?

Comment: На этом сервисе пару лет точно будут на месте! Проверено